# Session cookie not expiring on browser tab close

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to get my session cookie that tracks whether the user is landing on the homepage for the first time to get deleted when browser tab is closed. However, it seems like my VISITED cookie below keeps it's value of "yes" even when the browser tab is closed. So next time I visit the home page, the script doesn't run the redirect, since I'm checking for a "null" value for the VISITED cookie.

I'm using the carhartl cookie script.

```
/*  Save My Textbook Functionality */
$(function() {
    var COOKIE_NAME = 'textbook-cookie'; /* create cookie */
    var VISITED = 'visited' /* track where user has landed */
    var PATH = window.location.pathname;

    $( ".save-textbook-cc1" ).click(function() {
      $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'cc1', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    });
    /*$( ".save-textbook-cc2" ).click(function() {
      $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'cc2', { expires: 7, path: '/index.php' });
      alert("Textbook Saved as CC2!")
      $.cookie(VISITED, 'no', { expires: 7, path: '/index.php' });
    });*/

    $go = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
    $visited = $.cookie(VISITED);
    if ($go == 'cc1' && $visited == null && PATH == '/') {
        $.cookie(VISITED, 'yes', { path: '/' });
        window.location = "/core-connections-1";
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"session" cookies (lifetime only for the current session) do usually persist until the browser gets closed, not the tab.

Afaik, there is no way to change this because it is browser specific behaviour.

Comment: This code I posted doesn't work when the browser is closed either. @DanFromGermany

Comment: @Use real cookies through a HTTP header, not jquery soft cookies

Comment: How would I activate a real cookie through a link click event?

Comment: @AllureWebSolutions Make an ajax call to a simple serverside script that sets a cookie

Comment: It would be great if I could get a sample code for this or be pointed to a tutorial. I'm very much a newbie and can only implement pre-written script and not write from scratch. Thanks!